# Can't retrieve EmailTemplate or Folder metadata types via SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata

I have classic email templates in Production that I'd like to easily retrieve and deploy into Sandbox via `sfdx force:source:retrieve` and `sfdx force:source:deploy` commands.

I've tried

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate -u MyProductionOrg
```

...with "No results found".  I thought I would need the Folder so I tried

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Folder -u MyProductionOrg
```

...which didn't get any results either.

How am I supposed to retrieve these [metadata types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm)?  Not sure what I'm missing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try below command to retrieve email template

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:Custom_Template/Claim_Notification
```

Here `Custom_Template` is folder API name and `Claim_Notification` is the email template name.
Whenever we retrieve email template they must be retrieved the folder path must be mentioned and same goes for deployment

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath c:\Users\...\force-app\main\default\email\Custom_Template\Claim_Notification.email --json --loglevel fatal
```

While deploying it should be the path where your email template is physically located. However make sure the folder already exists in your org with the same name before deploying.

Comment: Perfert.  Spelling out the full `EmailTemplate:Template_Folder/Email_Template_Developer_Name` worked.  Note that just `EmailTemplate:Template_Folder` did not bring down every email template within that `Template_Folder`, so it seems you have to specify the exact email template that you'd like to pluck